# How to make a outline shader with custom attributes in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, outline

I am making a unity project like Dressing Room. The basic function is to change the fabric of a gameobj ( such as a shoe). So i want to achieve outline effect when the gameobj is selected by player, I have found that modify the source shader to a outline shader work well. But the source shader have normalmap and lightmap properties , the outline shader only have :

```
Shader "Outlined/Silhouetted Diffuse" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (.0,.0,.0,0)
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Outline ("Outline width", Range (0.0, 0.03)) = .01
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    }
```

So when the shader is changed the lightmap and normalmap properties lost at the same time. I have no idea how to add these two properties to the outline shader :

```
Shader "Outlined/Silhouetted Diffuse" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (.0,.0,.0,0)
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Outline ("Outline width", Range (0.0, 0.03)) = .01
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }

      //**********add these two properties ***********
        _BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {} 
        _LightMap ("Lightmap (RGB)", 2D) = "black" {} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Outline Shader: [Source](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Outlined_Diffuse_3)

```
    Shader "Outlined/Diffuse" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (.5,.5,.5,1)
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Outline ("Outline width", Range (.002, 0.03)) = .005
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    }

CGINCLUDE
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

struct appdata {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct v2f {
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

uniform float _Outline;
uniform float4 _OutlineColor;

v2f vert(appdata v) {
    // just make a copy of incoming vertex data but scaled according to normal direction
    v2f o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

    float3 norm   = mul ((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, v.normal);
    float2 offset = TransformViewToProjection(norm.xy);

    o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
    o.color = _OutlineColor;
    return o;
}
ENDCG

    SubShader {
        //Tags {"Queue" = "Geometry+100" }
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG

        // note that a vertex shader is specified here but its using the one above
        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Front
            ZWrite On
            ColorMask RGB
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            //Offset 50,50

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            half4 frag(v2f i) :COLOR { return i.color; }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    SubShader {
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG

        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Front
            ZWrite On
            ColorMask RGB
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles xbox360 ps3
            ENDCG
            SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine primary }
        }
    }

    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```